# How to write back to a csv file that was just read (c++)?

Tags: c++, csv

Im trying to write back to a csv file that was previously read in a program.  The program currently looks like this:

```
ifstream file;

    file.open ("file");

    e=0;

    while (file.good()) {

        getline ( file, infor,',');
        istringstream (infor) >> infoc;
        var1[e]=infoc;

        getline ( file, infor,',');
        istringstream (infor) >> infoc;
        var2[e]=infoc;

        getline ( file, infor,',');
        istringstream (infor) >> infoc;
        var3[e]=infoc;

        getline ( file, infor,',');
        istringstream (infor) >> infoc;
        var4[e]=infoc;

        getline ( file, infor,',');
        istringstream (infor) >> infoc;
        var5[e]=infoc;

        getline ( file, infor,',');
        istringstream (infor) >> infoc;
        var6[e]=infoc;

        getline ( file, infor,',');
        istringstream (infor) >> infoc;
        var7[e]=infoc;

        getline ( file, infor,',');
        istringstream (infor) >> infoc;
        var8[e]=infoc;

        getline ( file, infor,',');
        istringstream (infor) >> infoc;
        var9[e]=infoc;

        getline ( file, infor,',');
        istringstream (infor) >> infoc;
        var10[e]=infoc;

        getline ( file, infor,',');
        istringstream (infor) >> infoc;
        var11[e]=infoc;

        getline ( file, infor,',');
        istringstream (infor) >> infoc;
        var12[e]=infoc;

        getline ( file, infor,',');
        istringstream (infor) >> infoc;
        var13[e]=infoc;

        getline ( file, infor,',');
        istringstream (infor) >> infoc;
        var14[e]=infoc;

        getline ( file, infor,',');
        istringstream (infor) >> infoc;
        var15[e]=infoc;

        ++e;

    }



    var1[e] = var1[e] + v1;
    var2[e] = var2[e] + v2;
    var3[e] = var3[e] + v3;
    var4[e] = var4[e] + v4;
    var5[e] = var5[e] + v5;
    var6[e] = var6[e] + v6;
    var7[e] = var7[e] + v7;
    var8[e] = var8[e] + v8;
    var9[e] = var9[e] + v9;
    var10[e] = var10[e] + v10;
    var11[e] = var11[e] + v11;
    var12[e] = var12[e] + v12;
    var13[e] = var13[e] + v13;
    var14[e] = var14[e] + v14;
    var15[e] = var15[e] + v15;
    //WRITE TO compYTD

    file.close();
```

Before i close the file i want to write the new calculated variables back to the file, erasing everything that was previously read.  Is there a function that allows me to do this? Also is there a separate function that allows me to write back to this file, adding on to the lines already there?

Answer (score 0):

I personally would close the file, and then write the new values using something like this:

```
ofstream ofile("file.csv"); 

for(int i = 0; i < e; i++)
   ofile << var1[i] << ", " << var2[i] << ", " << var3[i] << ", " << ... endl;

ofile.close();
```

(Of course, it would be much easier if `var1`, `var2` etc were in an array or a vector - same for reading it in of course - would just be one instance of the `getline`, `istringstream`, etc.)

To append (add information to the end of) a file, you can use `ios_base::app` as a flag to an `ofstream`. So again, you close the input file, and open a the outuput in an `ofstream`:

```
    ofstream ofile("file.csv", ios_base::app);
```

Anything you write to the file will now be at the end of the file.

Comment: could i close the file i read and open the same one back up to write to? and would this add on to the existing data in the file or erase/overwrite it?

Comment: Unless you specify something else, `ofstream` will create a new empty file. This is the reason I suggested this method. However, you MUST do this AFTER you have read all the data. If you want to simultaneously read and write, you will have to have two different names on the files [ok, not strictly required in Unix/Linux/MacOS type OS's, but it's really rather unportable to RELY on that]

Comment: isnt there such thing as opening a file in append mode or something?

Comment: Yes, that will add the new values to the end of the file. But your question asks for "erase the old file and write new values", which is what I've described... "append" mode would fall under "specifying something else".

Comment: Ah, didn't read the second half of your "question part". See edit (in a few seconds).

Comment: ok thanks for clarifying that.  Im just confused on one thing.  You said ofstream will create a new empty file.  Does this mean i can designate the location of the file to be the same as the one read and then when i write back the read/edited values it would essentially be "overwriting" what was previously on file?

Comment: and im sorry but one other thing, when i write in append mode it automatically adds the new data to a new line on the opened file?

Comment: Yes, if you don't specify `ios_base::app` or `ios_base::in` as a flag on an `ofstream`, it will create a brand new file (and remove any old file by the same name, if there is one). If you `ios_base::app`, then any writes go to the end of the file. I suggest you write a tiny program that does this in a simple way (literally, it's just five lines or so that you need), before trying it with something complicated.